# SQL/MYSQL Update child under parent till null

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have a database table like this.

```
     userID         RefralID         balance
        1              0               0
        2              1               0
        3              2               0
        4              3               0
        5              8               0
```

now i want a MYSQL query to update the balance of each child under userID 1.
stuck there from 10 hours, but couldn't find desired Solution.

Results should like this if we update balance=balance + 10 where userID = '1'
as the 2,3,4 are child and grand child of '1' so their balance should be updated

```
     userID         RefralID         balance
        1              0               0
        2              1               10
        3              2               10
        4              3               10
        5              8               0
```

Comment: Can you post the expected result ?

Comment: Grisha its alredy posted just check

Comment: i have posted the expected result under my question.

Comment: Is number of child levels limited ?

Comment: No, number of child is not limited;

Comment: how do you determine which rows are child and grandchild?

Answer (score 2):

```
update tblA T2 join
 (
   SELECT 
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := userid FROM tblA WHERE refralid = _id limit 1) AS userid,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 1, @l := 0) vars,
        tblA m
    ) T1
ON T1._id = T2.userid  
set balance=balance+10 
where T2.userid<>1
```

---

```
@r := 1
T2.userid<>1 

The value 1 above is the userid=1
```

Could remove the @l (level) as that is for reference.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e606a/2

Comment: that worked cool but failed in case of...INSERT INTO users (refral_ID, balance ) VALUES
('0', '0'),
('1', '0'),
('1', '0'),
('3', '0'),
('8', '0'),
('1', '10');

Comment: the above comment values should update the balance for last ('1', '10')= 20

Comment: sorry for oversee the possibility of the data you post. If so, the query is not working for your case.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is :

```
create table temp1 (int id);
create table temp2 (int id);

insert into temp1 select ReferalID from your_table where userID = 1

while exists (select 1 from temp1)
begin
       truncate table temp2

       update your_table 
       set balance = balance + 10 
       where userID in (select * from temp1)

       insert into temp2 select * from temp1

       truncate table temp1

       insert into temp1 
       select ReferalID 
       from your_table 
       where userID in (select * from temp2)       
end
```